# Bootstrap 3, 3 items in list box, left align first, center 2nd, and right align 3rd

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have Bootstrap 3 framework with 3 items in an unordered list. I need the first one left aligned, the second one centered, and the third one right aligned.  I can float the last element with the :last-child selector, but I'm not sure how to figure out the automatic spacing of the middle child.

```
#icon-bar ul
{
   margin: 0 0 0 15px;
   padding: 0;
   list-style-type: none;
}

#icon-bar ul li { display: inline-block; width: 33%;}

#icon-bar ul li a
{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

#icon-bar ul li a:hover
{

}



<div class="col-sm-12 padding-0">
<div id="icon-bar">
<ul>
<li><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/370x75" ></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/370x75" ></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/370x75" ></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

[link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RmHb.jpg)

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using a `ul` with `li`s that have a defined width rather than using Bootstrap's grid system?

Comment: You're correct, just a habit of putting things in a list.  I just dropped the <ul> and put them in divs

Answer (score 0):

I have added bootstrap classes to UL and List.

```css
#icon-bar ul
{   
   list-style-type: none;
  
}

#icon-bar ul li { display: inline-block; }

#icon-bar ul li a
{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

#icon-bar ul li a:hover
{

}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="">
<div id="icon-bar">
<ul class="row">
<li class="col-xs-4"><a href="#" ><img src="http://placehold.it/370x75" ></a></li>
<li class="col-xs-4"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/370x75" ></a></li>
<li class="col-xs-4"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/370x75" ></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The use of the UL was not needed, I just used div containers instead